# Changing attributes of products that are already registered in magento

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.6

I have given several products the **default** attribute. I now want to change the attributes of these products to **artificial baits**.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible from the UI. It's possible to do that from the code and I believe I've seen some extensions in Magento connect.